# One additional slider appear when Inheriting from UISlider

Tags: ios, inheritance, storyboard, uislider, paintcode

I recently purchased paintcode. I used this to create a slider. In Xcode, when I, In my storyboard create an empty view and set it to a class `Slider.m` where my slider code is, and run this app, this happens:

[image]

My drawing code is inside -

> (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {}

My `Slider.h` is inheriting fram `UISlider`. If I inherits from say `UIButton`, only my drawing appears.

Why is that?

Comment: There is generally no need to use custom painting (`drawRect:`) for customizing a slider. You can simply provide the graphic parts to its instance - see  `setMaximumTrackImage:forState:` and alike. For a complete tutorial on that subject, you may want to use (the first google hit) http://www.getappninja.com/blog/how-to-make-a-custom-uislider

Comment: @Till I appreciate the tip. But I still wanna know why this happens (an extra slider appears when inheriting from uislider)

Comment: The reason is the fact that apple decided to use several subclasses within UISlider for all the UI handling (drawing, tracking, ...). As such, you drawRect method is rather pointless. Hence you should read about https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISlider.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UISlider and do as they suggest to - OR - create an entirely custom version by subclassing `UIView`.

Comment: @Till this may be a dumb question, but I'm fairly new to IOS. Say I use my custom drawing code, and inherits from UIView, how would I go about getting all the different methods from the UISlider class?

Comment: You would have to implement that entirely yourself, no inheritance. And that is, once again ;), the reason on why I urge you to use the standard UISlider and customize its appearance via the suggested methods. Have a look at the second link that I had supplied you with.

Comment: @Till That does look easier! The reason I made it the way I did was when I made a button, and used it's drawing code, and inherited from UIButton everything worked out great :) Guess the UISlider is way different. Anyway - Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The displayed results are reasoned in the fact that `UISlider` (among many other controls) in fact is composed of multiple subclasses which handle the drawing themselves. The results is a highly optimized display code which can not properly be overridden using `drawRect:` on the `UISlider` only. You would have to override several other, partially closed implementations of that composed control.

In fact, there is a much easier and much more performant solution which is providing the graphical elements you wish to customize to `UISlider`. A nice introduction on that subject can be found on Apple's conceptual introduction to [Sliders](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISlider.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UISlider).

There some smaller pitfalls though - one of them is the fact that a `UISlider`'s thumb does not "like" to be replaced by something with a different size. Those are however covered by many tutorials - one of those would be [how-to-make-a-custom-uislider](http://www.getappninja.com/blog/how-to-make-a-custom-uislider).

**As a rule of thumb: avoid subclassing and overriding `drawRect:` when possible by any means as it will vastly degrade the performance of your UI.**

Instead look at solutions that make use of the `UIAppearance` protocol for controls that do not provide interfaces for customizing. `UISlider` however does provide them, so go for those.

This would be my approach priority list:

1. Check very carefully if the control in question does allow customizing by providing images etc.
2. Check if the control in question adheres to the `UIAppearance` protocol.
3. Use subclassing and possibly overriding `drawRect:`
4. When it turns out that the control in question appears to handle `drawRect:` in a "weird" way, subclass `UIView` and recreate the missing logic yourself.